# How to do proper error handling in CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, error-handling

I'm using PHP's Codeigniter to build my application, and I sometimes feel like I'm being drowned in error handling. I'm adding "failsafes" everywhere something could fail. Here are some examples:

In the model:

1. If not all model method parameters supplied, return false
2. For every mysql query, if query failed, return false
3. Depending on the situation, if number of rows of query is < 1 (where it would have to be > 0), return false

In the controller:

1. If controller method has missing required parameters, return false
2. If the called model returns false, redirect with an error flash message, or show error view

What I'd like to know is, am I overdoing it? I feel like it may be unnecessary to test every mysql query, but then again, if one of them does break for whatever reason, the rest of the script would fail or mess something up for the user.

And lastly, in all the above stages of error handling, which places would it be appropriate to log the error to a file?

Comment: Models should throw exceptions and catch and resolve the ones they can and re-throw anything else. If/How to present a an exception to the user is the job of the controller/view.

Comment: Keep in mind that handling errors in a dev environment and handling errors in a live, user-facing environment are probably going to be two different things. @Orangepill is right, though. Catch exceptions within the model and then use your controllers/views to decide if you should present the full-blown debug dump or just tell the user that you had an "oopsie."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are having so many returns in one function, your code is poorly structured. that, and if you are running raw SQL queries, unless you are accessing meta-data, you may be better off handing off to models (something which CI has).

For your methods, consider type-hinting. Something written as:

```
 function FunctionNameHere($user, $id, $test) {
 }
```

May be better written by considering passing in a `User` object, which allows you to then do this:

```
 function FunctionNameHere(User $user, $test) {
 }
```

Which does all your "incorrect parameter set" validation for you and will throw an error.

For the SQL queries, consider using models, which will allow you to, once again, retrieve objects. No object? `NULL` gets returned. Problem solved.

Instead of returning integer values, consider throwing `Exception`s (and don't be afraid to extend the `Exception` class, which then allows you to catch different exceptions in different blocks!). This will allow you to neatly wrap some of the common error cases in your code (like throwing a flashy error box to the user. Done using exception? Check).

Comment: I'm not following what you mean by passing in the User object. Can you elaborate? As for SQL, I am using models to do the queries. If the model returns false, then I know it didn't work--but I still check for it within the model that calls THAT model, and consequently, check it in the controller. Or perhaps I am misunderstanding you somewhere. Can you link me to some articles that could elaborate further on how to do this? Thank you.

Comment: @user371699: are your model distinct objects? If yes, you can type-hint your functions to only accept this type of parameter. If it is false, or null, or anything that is not that type of object, your code will throw an error (which can be converted into an exception at will). Regarding the parameters, all I did was to coalesce possible parameters you might pass around into a model reference.